# bootstrap columns stacking on each other when supposed not to

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3x4 columns on my website which makes equal to 12 columns in total. But for some reason they happen to stack on each other, even tho there is enough space for them. I can't figure out what causes them to collapse. I have a little demo, you can see red boxes stacking on each other.

HTML:

```
<div class="row portfolio">
    <div class="body_container2">
    <h1 class="display portfolio_h1">Portfolio</h1>

    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Codepen:

http://codepen.io/Limpuls/pen/Qpyygj

Comment: You just need to wrap your `col-lg-4`'s with `<div class="row"> //col-lg-4's here</div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
<div class="body_container2">
<h1 class="display portfolio_h1">Portfolio</h1>
<div class="row portfolio">
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMeexb

Comment: @Limpuls Glad to help you! If my answer solved your issue, please accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

All the column need to be **directly in** a row (the parent had to be a row), like that

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

You can see it working here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZbbaQ